# Bitmapdata.Scan0 return pointer to zero filled array

Tags: c++, gdi+

I have such code

```
Bitmap bmp(i_texWidth, i_texHeight);
std::unique_ptr<Graphics> pBmpGr(Graphics::FromImage(&bmp));
SolidBrush brush(Color(255, 168, 128, 192));
assert(pBmpGr->FillRectangle(&brush, 0, 0, i_texWidth, i_texHeight) == Ok);
BitmapData bitmapData;
auto rect = Rect(0, 0, i_texWidth, i_texHeight);
bmp.LockBits(&rect, ImageLockModeWrite, PixelFormat24bppRGB, &bitmapData);
```

After this array pointed by bitmapData.Scan0 is filled by 0, despite bitmap pixels have correct values, I checked this using bmp.GetPixel.
I tried different pixels formats it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageLockModeWrite` isn't required to copy the pixel data to the array.  Instead, it is just required to provide an array that you can fill, which is then written to the image.

Change that to `ImageLockModeWrite | ImageLockModeRead`